# Typescript including types and optional arguments

Tags: typescript

Write a JavaScript program to list the properties of a JavaScript object 
Sample object :

```
var student = { 
name : "David Rayy", 
sclass : "VI", 
rollno : 12 };
```

The question is to add typing, optional and default arguments in this program using Typescript.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service, try doing it yourself first.

Comment: There is no need to add any types to the code sample you included: typescript will correctly infer all the types needed here so you should answer the question by saying the code is fine as it is.

Answer (score 0):

> including types and optional arguments

Types and optional *members*. Just an example:

```
var student: {name: string, sclass: string, rollno: number, somethingElse?: number} = { 
name : "David Rayy", 
sclass : "VI", 
rollno : 12 };
```